# Unmanaged Exports - DllExport and DllImport collide?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I'm testing out the Unmanaged Exports package. I created a test class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [DllImport(@"SomeOther.dll")]
    private static extern int ProcessRequest(XmlDocument request, XmlDocument responce);

    [DllExport]
    public static int TestDLL(int x)
    {
        return x + 2;
    }

    [DllExport]
    public static int TestRequest(XmlDocument request, XmlDocument responce)
    {
        //ProcessRequest(ref request, ref responce);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then I build it and test with dumpbin /exports to see if my functions are really visible.
And for the above code I would get only one function in output:

> ```
>   ordinal hint RVA      name
>         1    0 000027CE TestRequest
> ```

And if I change the order of methods in my class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [DllImport(@"SomeOther.dll")]
    private static extern int ProcessRequest(XmlDocument request, XmlDocument responce);

    [DllExport]
    public static int TestRequest(XmlDocument request, XmlDocument responce)
    {
        //ProcessRequest(ref request, ref responce);
        return 0;
    }

    [DllExport]
    public static int TestDLL(int x)
    {
        return x + 2;
    }
}
```

The output of dumpbin changes to:

> ```
>   ordinal hint RVA      name
>         1    0 000027CE TestDll
> ```

At last, if I put the DllImport part after exported methods, I would finally get:

> ```
>    ordinal hint RVA      name
>          1    0 0000276E TestRequest
>          0    1 0000275E TestDLL
> ```

Why is this happening? Is there an error in my code?

Comment: It's a pretty flaky tool, the author doesn't accept bug reports.  Do what works.